# Failed to load the widgetset.nocache.js

Tags: grails

I'm trying to start complex grails project. It compiles without errors, but when I ran the app and try to open it in browser I have this alert: [alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYhm2.png)

Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/myPath.widgetset.nocache.js?1495020123990

I found some solutions but they were for maven project (I have graddle) or some eclipse troubles (I work in intelijji idea).

Any ideas?

Comment: What grails version (assuming 3 because of `gradle`)?  How do you add vaadin?  Do you need your own widgetset?  If yes: compile it first

Comment: @cfrick, grails version 2.4.4. I add vaadin by adding dependency to BuildConfig.groovy:  compile 'org.grails.plugins:vaadin:' + vaadinVersion  compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-push:' + vaadinVersion. Vaadin version:7.6.1 My project compilled without errors.

Comment: You have build the widgetset beforehand.  This is documented for that plugin http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.de/2013/06/vaadin-7-and-grails-how-to-compile.html and also in the vaadin wiki.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will have the same problem. In my case grails compile command not compilled the vaadin. So I have to compile it with another command: 
grails vaadin:compile
It helped me.